# How to use Use git+gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to configure Git + Gerrit but I don't know how to proceed; I have some questions:

1. Can we use our own Gerrit server or can we use online `gerrit` servers also?
2. How my project will be associated with Gerrit?

What I understood is when we are going to commit any changes from Eclipse to Git they firstly go to Gerrit for code review, and when some one accepts the code then and then only code is committed to Git: is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually you host your own Gerrit server. There is AFAIK only one commercial Gerrit holster, GerritForge.
2. Gerrit will act as your git server. You will not be able to push your changes to another server and then import to Gerrit - it has to be the source of truth. But you can use replication to sync (outgoing) to other severs.
3. You don't have to use a review workflow. Gerrit can be configured (on a per-project level) to allow certain user groups to push to e.g. some or all branches directly. But usually (to really make use of Gerrit) your devs will push to the Gerrit sever and then others will review and submit it (through the web interface or through the Mylyn integration).